# Do I use Merge or Join to compare two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to datasets, `old` and `new`.  Both should have three columns in common: `mmsi`,`d`,`ts`.

```
old
    mmsi d  lat     lon     ts
0   0   93  40.3601 122.179 1458213600
1   0   93  40.3601 122.179 1458214200
2   0   93  40.3601 122.179 1458214800
3   0   93  40.3601 122.179 1458217200
4   0   93  40.3601 122.179 1458220800

new

    mmsi d   ts          lat            lon
0   0   77  1458211800  46.3675533333   48.01107
1   0   77  1458212400  46.3675533333   48.01107
2   0   77  1458213000  46.3675533333   48.01107
3   0   77  1458215400  46.3675533333   48.01107
4   0   77  1458219000  46.3675533333   48.01107
```

The two sets should have `mmsi`,`d`,`ts` in common, but when I perform a merge, the shape of the resulting data frame is much different than the shape of `old` or `new`.

Do I use Merge of Join in this instance?  How can I combine both dataframes so that I can compare `lat`and `lon`?

Comment: Sorry are you asking how to tell if some values are only present in left/right/both? if so you can do `old.merge(new, on=['mms'i,'d','ts'], how='outer', indicator=True)` this will add `_merge` column telling where the data is present in left/right/both

Comment: Im interested in the mmsi, d, ts couples that are in both data sets.  So will that line of code do the trick?

Comment: No you can remove `how` param ` or pass `how='inner'` to find only where values exist in both dfs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with parameter `how='inner'`:

```
print pd.merge(new,old,on=['mmsi','d','ts'], how='inner')
```

Sample:

```
print new
   mmsi   d          ts        lat       lon
0     0  77  1458213600  46.367553  48.01107
1     0  77  1458214200  46.367553  48.01107
2     0  77  1458213000  46.367553  48.01107
3     0  77  1458215400  46.367553  48.01107
4     0  77  1458217200  46.367553  48.01107

print old
   mmsi   d       lat      lon          ts
0     0  77  48.01107  122.179  1458213600
1     0  77  48.01107  122.179  1458214200
2     0  77  48.01107  122.179  1458214800
3     0  77  48.01107  122.179  1458217200
4     0  77  48.01107  122.179  1458220800

#added custom suffixes
print pd.merge(new,old,on=['mmsi','d','ts'], how='inner', suffixes=('_new','_old'))
   mmsi   d          ts    lat_new   lon_new   lat_old  lon_old
0     0  77  1458213600  46.367553  48.01107  48.01107  122.179
1     0  77  1458214200  46.367553  48.01107  48.01107  122.179
2     0  77  1458217200  46.367553  48.01107  48.01107  122.179
```

Comment: Great, this works well.  Thanks